# Does the map to a variety from its normalization give a bijection on codimension 1 points?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a variety and $\varphi : Y \to X$ its normalization. Suppose that $\dim X \geq 2$.

Does $\varphi$ always give a bijection between codimension 1 points of $Y$ and those of $X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $k$ is of characteristic not two. Let $X=\operatorname{Spec} k[t^2-1,t(t^2-1),u]$, the product of the nodal cubic and a line. The normalization map is $Y=\operatorname{Spec} k[t,u]\to X$ in the obvious way, and the codimension-one point $(t^2-1,t(t^2-1))$ has two preimages, $(t-1)$ and $(t+1)$.